# MongoDB Fetch Data via php

Tags: php, mongodb

i tried to figure out for like 3 hours how i could read data from my mongodb clusters i did many researches but none of them do work im using the New Library here is how i tried to fetch data

```
$connection = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("Connection String");
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query(['Name' => "Max"],['LastName' => "Miller"]); 

$result = $connection->executeQuery("dbName.CollectionName", $query);

if($result){
  echo "Username Exists!";
} else {
  echo "Username does not exist!";
};
```

I've tried everything but nothing seems to work i would be glad if one one you developers could help me and no my question was not already answered the other posts were talking about the old driver and im talking about the new one

Comment: Can you explain, what is not working? Are you getting any errors? This will help others to help you quickly.

Comment: It just says Username exists without even entering any name

Comment: If your $result variable is having non-zero value, then if($result) will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

If your $result variable is having non-zero value, then if($result) will always be true.

You may want to try var_dump($result) and that would give you an idea. Also check your error logs to see if you are getting any warnings.

You may also want to try if(true === $result) for a strict comparison.

Comment: i tried what you said but it also didn't work and the var_dump($result) gave me this output
object(MongoDB\Driver\Cursor)#3 (10) { ["database"]=> string(9) "UserData" ["collection"]=> string(8) "accounts" ["query"]=> object(MongoDB\Driver\Query)#2 (3) { ["filter"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (1) { ["FirstName"]=> string(0) "" }